# Mysql check for unique data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three data columns:

```
DATE          ID1    ID2
//
2012-10-01      5      9
2012-10-01      3      6
2012-10-01      1      7
2012-10-01      0      2
2012-10-01      8      4
//
2012-10-08      6      5
2012-10-08      5      8      >>> should FLAG!
//
2012-10-15      9      6
2012-10-15      3      4
2012-10-15      9      7      >>> should FLAG!
//
```

For each DATE grouping, the IDs in ID1 and ID2 should be unique.

After I've entered a year's worth of data, what query can I run to check that I haven't fat fingered any IDs?

I can manually check by entering the date each time:

```
SELECT id FROM table a JOIN table b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.date = 2012-10-01 AND a.ID1 = b.ID1 ...
```

However, for a year's worth of dates, this isn't practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT date, id1, id2 FROM data d 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM data d2 
    WHERE d2.date = d.date AND ( 
        d2.id1 = d.id2 OR d2.id2 = d.id1 
        OR (d.id1=d2.id1 AND d.id2 <> d2.id2) 
        OR (d.id2=d2.id2 AND d.id1 <> d2.id1)
    )
)
```

Which will select the rows that have an id matching the other id from the same date, or with just one of the ids matching (but not both).

**Edit**: Fixed for second case noted by @a1ex07

**Edit 2**: Alternative below.

Or if you prefer, this is also equivalent:

```
SELECT d.date, d.id1, d.id2 FROM data d 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT date, id FROM (
        SELECT date, id1 AS id FROM data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT date, id2 AS id FROM data
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY date, id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS dupes 
WHERE d.date = dupes.date AND (d.id1 = dupes.id OR d.id2 = dupes.id)
```

Comment: It's not gonna catch the second example (duplicate id1 for a date)

Comment: Second example is giving me a 'Every derived table must have its own alias' error...

Comment: Added the alias, try it now.

Comment: 'Unknown column 'd.date' in 'field list'

Comment: I'm assuming you have a table of the form `data (date ..., id1 ..., id2 ...)`.  Otherwise, adjust to the names you actually used.  Case may matter depending on your system and settings.

Comment: Ah brilliant got it to work! I had ticks around my selects which were interfering with the aliases? Removed them and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could `group by` the date and `count`:

```
SELECT   `date`, `id1`, COUNT (*)
FROM     `my_table`
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

And repeat the process for `id2`.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of table creation put unique constraint on ID1 and ID2.

Comment: This does not work because the same id's are used for different dates.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the slickest solution, but I think it does what you are looking for. Basically I created a temporary table (not a real temp table, just a table you can drop later if you don't need it) that stores the ids from col1 and col2 in a single field. Then you insert the col1 and col2 values into the temp table and run a simple query to pull any ids that have a count > 1. I added the colName field to the temp table in case you need to track which id column the value came from.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    date DATE,
    id SMALLINT,
    colName VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT date, id1, 'id1'
    FROM table;

INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT date, id2, 'id2'
    FROM table;

SELECT date, id, COUNT(id) AS total
FROM temp
GROUP BY date, id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1;
```

If you run this often you could create a stored procedure and call it that way.